# What happens if you seek() to the middle of a multi-byte UTF-8 character and call read(1)?

Tags: python, utf-8

In Python 3, `read`(*size*) has the following documentation:

> Read and return at most *size* characters from the stream as a single `str`. If size is negative or `None`, reads until EOF.

But suppose that you `seek()` to the *middle* of a multi-byte UTF-8 character. What will `read(1)` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial unicode character can't be decoded so python will raise a `UnicodeDecodeError`. But you can recover from the problem. The UTF-8 encoding is built to be self-healing, meaning that the first byte of the character sequence (0x00-0x7f or 0xc0-0xfd) will not appear in any other byte, so you just need to keep seeking backwards by 1 byte until the decode works.

```
>>> def read_unicode(fp, position, count):
...     while position >= 0:
...         fp.seek(position)
...         try:
...             return fp.read(count)
...         except UnicodeDecodeError:
...             position -= 1
...     raise UnicodeDecodeError("File not decodable")
... 
>>> open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8').write("学"*10000)
10000
>>> f=open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
>>> f.seek(32)
32
>>> f.read(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 0: invalid start byte
>>> read_unicode(f, 32, 1)
'学'
```

Answer (score 0):

Text streams in Python 3 don't support arbitrary seek offsets, you're only supposed to use offsets of 0, or values returned by `tell` with `whence` of `SEEK_SET`. Everything else is undefined or unsupported behavior. See [the docs for `TextIOBase.seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek).

Sure, in practice, you might get `UnicodeDecodeError`, but that is not a guarantee. As soon as you violate the API contractual requirements, it can do whatever it wants.